# sha3-256 of a cell text in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, sha-3

I know you can do sha1 and others on google sheets but is there a way to do sha3-256

```
secret: test123

hash 3054762b0a8b31adfe79efb3bc7718624627cc99c7c8f39bfa591ce6854ac05d
```

Comment: Not natively. The current list of [hash algorithms supported](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/digest-algorithm.html) does not cover the sha-3 standard. You'll either have to implement it in App Script yourself or try to find an existing implementation in javascript that can be used-in or migrated-to Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the hash of SHA3-256 type from the text of `test123` as the HEX data.
- You want to put the value to a cell of Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.
- **You want to use the function as the custom function.**

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Issue:

In the current stage, the hash of SHA3-256 cannot be directly retrieved using the built-in methods of Google Apps Script. So as the several workarounds, it is required to create the script by yourself and/or use the library of Javascript. This is mentioned by [Dimu Designs's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043163/sha3-256-of-a-cell-text-in-google-spreadsheet#comment102487634_58043163).

#### Workaround:

In this answer, a Javascript library is used. It's [jsSHA](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA). Fortunately, it was found that this library could be used at Google Apps Script. Using this, the text data is converted to the hash of SHA3-256.

Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

When you want to use this function as the custom function, I would like to recommend the following method. Please copy and paste the following script to your script editor. The script of jsSHA was downloaded from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/master/src/sha3.js`.

```
function myFunction(value) {
  var obj = new jsSHA("SHA3-256", "TEXT");
  obj.update(value);
  var hexHash = obj.getHash("HEX");
  return hexHash;
}

/*
 A JavaScript implementation of the SHA family of hashes, as
 defined in FIPS PUB 180-4 and FIPS PUB 202, as well as the corresponding
 HMAC implementation as defined in FIPS PUB 198a

 Copyright 2008-2018 Brian Turek, 1998-2009 Paul Johnston & Contributors
 Distributed under the BSD License
 See http://caligatio.github.com/jsSHA/ for more information
*/
'use strict';(function(L){function u(d,b,h){var c=0,a=[],l=0,e,m,r,g,k,f,p,v,A=!1,n=[],u=[],w,z=!1,x=!1,t=-1;h=h||{};e=h.encoding||"UTF8";w=h.numRounds||1;if(w!==parseInt(w,10)||1>w)throw Error("numRounds must a integer >= 1");if(0===d.lastIndexOf("SHA3-",0)||0===d.lastIndexOf("SHAKE",0)){var C=6;f=B;v=function(c){var a=[],e;for(e=0;5>e;e+=1)a[e]=c[e].slice();return a};t=1;if("SHA3-224"===d)k=1152,g=224;else if("SHA3-256"===d)k=1088,g=256;else if("SHA3-384"===d)k=832,g=384;else if("SHA3-512"===d)k=
576,g=512;else if("SHAKE128"===d)k=1344,g=-1,C=31,x=!0;else if("SHAKE256"===d)k=1088,g=-1,C=31,x=!0;else throw Error("Chosen SHA variant is not supported");p=function(c,a,e,g,d){e=k;var b=C,m,l=[],f=e>>>5,h=0,r=a>>>5;for(m=0;m<r&&a>=e;m+=f)g=B(c.slice(m,m+f),g),a-=e;c=c.slice(m);for(a%=e;c.length<f;)c.push(0);m=a>>>3;c[m>>2]^=b<<m%4*8;c[f-1]^=2147483648;for(g=B(c,g);32*l.length<d;){c=g[h%5][h/5|0];l.push(c.b);if(32*l.length>=d)break;l.push(c.a);h+=1;0===64*h%e&&B(null,g)}return l}}else throw Error("Chosen SHA variant is not supported");
r=D(b,e,t);m=y(d);this.setHMACKey=function(a,b,l){var h;if(!0===A)throw Error("HMAC key already set");if(!0===z)throw Error("Cannot set HMAC key after calling update");if(!0===x)throw Error("SHAKE is not supported for HMAC");e=(l||{}).encoding||"UTF8";b=D(b,e,t)(a);a=b.binLen;b=b.value;h=k>>>3;l=h/4-1;if(h<a/8){for(b=p(b,a,0,y(d),g);b.length<=l;)b.push(0);b[l]&=4294967040}else if(h>a/8){for(;b.length<=l;)b.push(0);b[l]&=4294967040}for(a=0;a<=l;a+=1)n[a]=b[a]^909522486,u[a]=b[a]^1549556828;m=f(n,m);
c=k;A=!0};this.update=function(e){var b,g,d,h=0,p=k>>>5;b=r(e,a,l);e=b.binLen;g=b.value;b=e>>>5;for(d=0;d<b;d+=p)h+k<=e&&(m=f(g.slice(d,d+p),m),h+=k);c+=h;a=g.slice(h>>>5);l=e%k;z=!0};this.getHash=function(e,b){var h,f,r,k;if(!0===A)throw Error("Cannot call getHash after setting HMAC key");r=E(b);if(!0===x){if(-1===r.shakeLen)throw Error("shakeLen must be specified in options");g=r.shakeLen}switch(e){case "HEX":h=function(a){return F(a,g,t,r)};break;case "B64":h=function(a){return G(a,g,t,r)};break;
case "BYTES":h=function(a){return H(a,g,t)};break;case "ARRAYBUFFER":try{f=new ArrayBuffer(0)}catch(q){throw Error("ARRAYBUFFER not supported by this environment");}h=function(a){return I(a,g,t)};break;default:throw Error("format must be HEX, B64, BYTES, or ARRAYBUFFER");}k=p(a.slice(),l,c,v(m),g);for(f=1;f<w;f+=1)!0===x&&0!==g%32&&(k[k.length-1]&=16777215>>>24-g%32),k=p(k,g,0,y(d),g);return h(k)};this.getHMAC=function(e,b){var h,r,n,w;if(!1===A)throw Error("Cannot call getHMAC without first setting HMAC key");
n=E(b);switch(e){case "HEX":h=function(a){return F(a,g,t,n)};break;case "B64":h=function(a){return G(a,g,t,n)};break;case "BYTES":h=function(a){return H(a,g,t)};break;case "ARRAYBUFFER":try{h=new ArrayBuffer(0)}catch(M){throw Error("ARRAYBUFFER not supported by this environment");}h=function(a){return I(a,g,t)};break;default:throw Error("outputFormat must be HEX, B64, BYTES, or ARRAYBUFFER");}r=p(a.slice(),l,c,v(m),g);w=f(u,y(d));w=p(r,g,k,w,g);return h(w)}}function f(d,b){this.a=d;this.b=b}function F(d,
b,h,c){var a="";b/=8;var l,e,m;m=-1===h?3:0;for(l=0;l<b;l+=1)e=d[l>>>2]>>>8*(m+l%4*h),a+="0123456789abcdef".charAt(e>>>4&15)+"0123456789abcdef".charAt(e&15);return c.outputUpper?a.toUpperCase():a}function G(d,b,h,c){var a="",l=b/8,e,m,f,g;g=-1===h?3:0;for(e=0;e<l;e+=3)for(m=e+1<l?d[e+1>>>2]:0,f=e+2<l?d[e+2>>>2]:0,f=(d[e>>>2]>>>8*(g+e%4*h)&255)<<16|(m>>>8*(g+(e+1)%4*h)&255)<<8|f>>>8*(g+(e+2)%4*h)&255,m=0;4>m;m+=1)8*e+6*m<=b?a+="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(f>>>
6*(3-m)&63):a+=c.b64Pad;return a}function H(d,b,h){var c="";b/=8;var a,l,e;e=-1===h?3:0;for(a=0;a<b;a+=1)l=d[a>>>2]>>>8*(e+a%4*h)&255,c+=String.fromCharCode(l);return c}function I(d,b,h){b/=8;var c,a=new ArrayBuffer(b),l,e;e=new Uint8Array(a);l=-1===h?3:0;for(c=0;c<b;c+=1)e[c]=d[c>>>2]>>>8*(l+c%4*h)&255;return a}function E(d){var b={outputUpper:!1,b64Pad:"=",shakeLen:-1};d=d||{};b.outputUpper=d.outputUpper||!1;!0===d.hasOwnProperty("b64Pad")&&(b.b64Pad=d.b64Pad);if(!0===d.hasOwnProperty("shakeLen")){if(0!==
d.shakeLen%8)throw Error("shakeLen must be a multiple of 8");b.shakeLen=d.shakeLen}if("boolean"!==typeof b.outputUpper)throw Error("Invalid outputUpper formatting option");if("string"!==typeof b.b64Pad)throw Error("Invalid b64Pad formatting option");return b}function D(d,b,h){switch(b){case "UTF8":case "UTF16BE":case "UTF16LE":break;default:throw Error("encoding must be UTF8, UTF16BE, or UTF16LE");}switch(d){case "HEX":d=function(c,a,b){var e=c.length,d,f,g,k,q,p;if(0!==e%2)throw Error("String of HEX type must be in byte increments");
a=a||[0];b=b||0;q=b>>>3;p=-1===h?3:0;for(d=0;d<e;d+=2){f=parseInt(c.substr(d,2),16);if(isNaN(f))throw Error("String of HEX type contains invalid characters");k=(d>>>1)+q;for(g=k>>>2;a.length<=g;)a.push(0);a[g]|=f<<8*(p+k%4*h)}return{value:a,binLen:4*e+b}};break;case "TEXT":d=function(c,a,d){var e,m,f=0,g,k,q,p,v,n;a=a||[0];d=d||0;q=d>>>3;if("UTF8"===b)for(n=-1===h?3:0,g=0;g<c.length;g+=1)for(e=c.charCodeAt(g),m=[],128>e?m.push(e):2048>e?(m.push(192|e>>>6),m.push(128|e&63)):55296>e||57344<=e?m.push(224|
e>>>12,128|e>>>6&63,128|e&63):(g+=1,e=65536+((e&1023)<<10|c.charCodeAt(g)&1023),m.push(240|e>>>18,128|e>>>12&63,128|e>>>6&63,128|e&63)),k=0;k<m.length;k+=1){v=f+q;for(p=v>>>2;a.length<=p;)a.push(0);a[p]|=m[k]<<8*(n+v%4*h);f+=1}else if("UTF16BE"===b||"UTF16LE"===b)for(n=-1===h?2:0,m="UTF16LE"===b&&1!==h||"UTF16LE"!==b&&1===h,g=0;g<c.length;g+=1){e=c.charCodeAt(g);!0===m&&(k=e&255,e=k<<8|e>>>8);v=f+q;for(p=v>>>2;a.length<=p;)a.push(0);a[p]|=e<<8*(n+v%4*h);f+=2}return{value:a,binLen:8*f+d}};break;case "B64":d=
function(c,a,b){var e=0,d,f,g,k,q,p,n,u;if(-1===c.search(/^[a-zA-Z0-9=+\/]+$/))throw Error("Invalid character in base-64 string");f=c.indexOf("=");c=c.replace(/\=/g,"");if(-1!==f&&f<c.length)throw Error("Invalid '=' found in base-64 string");a=a||[0];b=b||0;p=b>>>3;u=-1===h?3:0;for(f=0;f<c.length;f+=4){q=c.substr(f,4);for(g=k=0;g<q.length;g+=1)d="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".indexOf(q[g]),k|=d<<18-6*g;for(g=0;g<q.length-1;g+=1){n=e+p;for(d=n>>>2;a.length<=d;)a.push(0);
a[d]|=(k>>>16-8*g&255)<<8*(u+n%4*h);e+=1}}return{value:a,binLen:8*e+b}};break;case "BYTES":d=function(c,a,b){var e,d,f,g,k,n;a=a||[0];b=b||0;f=b>>>3;n=-1===h?3:0;for(d=0;d<c.length;d+=1)e=c.charCodeAt(d),k=d+f,g=k>>>2,a.length<=g&&a.push(0),a[g]|=e<<8*(n+k%4*h);return{value:a,binLen:8*c.length+b}};break;case "ARRAYBUFFER":try{d=new ArrayBuffer(0)}catch(c){throw Error("ARRAYBUFFER not supported by this environment");}d=function(c,a,b){var d,f,n,g,k,q;a=a||[0];b=b||0;f=b>>>3;k=-1===h?3:0;q=new Uint8Array(c);
for(d=0;d<c.byteLength;d+=1)g=d+f,n=g>>>2,a.length<=n&&a.push(0),a[n]|=q[d]<<8*(k+g%4*h);return{value:a,binLen:8*c.byteLength+b}};break;default:throw Error("format must be HEX, TEXT, B64, BYTES, or ARRAYBUFFER");}return d}function z(d,b){return 32<b?(b-=32,new f(d.b<<b|d.a>>>32-b,d.a<<b|d.b>>>32-b)):0!==b?new f(d.a<<b|d.b>>>32-b,d.b<<b|d.a>>>32-b):d}function n(d,b){return new f(d.a^b.a,d.b^b.b)}function y(d){var b=[];if(0===d.lastIndexOf("SHA3-",0)||0===d.lastIndexOf("SHAKE",0))for(d=0;5>d;d+=1)b[d]=
[new f(0,0),new f(0,0),new f(0,0),new f(0,0),new f(0,0)];else throw Error("No SHA variants supported");return b}function B(d,b){var h,c,a,l,e=[],m=[];if(null!==d)for(c=0;c<d.length;c+=2)b[(c>>>1)%5][(c>>>1)/5|0]=n(b[(c>>>1)%5][(c>>>1)/5|0],new f(d[c+1],d[c]));for(h=0;24>h;h+=1){l=y("SHA3-");for(c=0;5>c;c+=1){a=b[c][0];var r=b[c][1],g=b[c][2],k=b[c][3],q=b[c][4];e[c]=new f(a.a^r.a^g.a^k.a^q.a,a.b^r.b^g.b^k.b^q.b)}for(c=0;5>c;c+=1)m[c]=n(e[(c+4)%5],z(e[(c+1)%5],1));for(c=0;5>c;c+=1)for(a=0;5>a;a+=1)b[c][a]=
n(b[c][a],m[c]);for(c=0;5>c;c+=1)for(a=0;5>a;a+=1)l[a][(2*c+3*a)%5]=z(b[c][a],J[c][a]);for(c=0;5>c;c+=1)for(a=0;5>a;a+=1)b[c][a]=n(l[c][a],new f(~l[(c+1)%5][a].a&l[(c+2)%5][a].a,~l[(c+1)%5][a].b&l[(c+2)%5][a].b));b[0][0]=n(b[0][0],K[h])}return b}var J,K;K=[new f(0,1),new f(0,32898),new f(2147483648,32906),new f(2147483648,2147516416),new f(0,32907),new f(0,2147483649),new f(2147483648,2147516545),new f(2147483648,32777),new f(0,138),new f(0,136),new f(0,2147516425),new f(0,2147483658),new f(0,2147516555),
new f(2147483648,139),new f(2147483648,32905),new f(2147483648,32771),new f(2147483648,32770),new f(2147483648,128),new f(0,32778),new f(2147483648,2147483658),new f(2147483648,2147516545),new f(2147483648,32896),new f(0,2147483649),new f(2147483648,2147516424)];J=[[0,36,3,41,18],[1,44,10,45,2],[62,6,43,15,61],[28,55,25,21,56],[27,20,39,8,14]];"function"===typeof define&&define.amd?define(function(){return u}):"undefined"!==typeof exports?("undefined"!==typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=
u),exports=u):L.jsSHA=u})(this);
```

#### Usage:

From your situation, I thought that you might want to use this as the custom function. Because from your situation, I thought that you might be using it as `=myFunction(test123)`. This can be seen at [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043163/sha3-256-of-a-cell-text-in-google-spreadsheet#comment102528261_58059298). In this case, `884bad3ef9aa410492a8c2e256fb3e3a3c9043c0dca257c185861dc1b0496518` is returned. Because `#NAME?` is used as the text. It's the same with `=myFunction("#NAME?")`. The reason of your current issue is this.

If you want to run the script as the custom function, please put `=myFunction("test123")`. If the text of `test123` is put to the cell "A1", you can use `=myFunction(A1)`.

When `=myFunction("test123")` is put to the cell "A1", `3054762b0a8b31adfe79efb3bc7718624627cc99c7c8f39bfa591ce6854ac05d` can be retrie4ved.

#### Reference:

- [jsSHA](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA)

Comment: @manxuz I noticed your issue. I thought that you want to use the function as the custom function, and you are putting `=myFunction(test123)` to a cell. In this case, `=myFunction(test123)` returns `884bad3ef9aa410492a8c2e256fb3e3a3c9043c0dca257c185861dc1b0496518`, because `=myFunction("#NAME?")` is run. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Making minor tweaks to Tanaike's answer we can achieve your original request. The final code looks like this:

```
function SHA3_256(clearText) {
  var url =
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Caligatio/jsSHA/master/src/sha3.js";
  var js = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  if (js.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    eval(js.getContentText());
    var obj = new jsSHA("SHA3-256", "TEXT");
    obj.update(clearText);
    var hexHash = obj.getHash("HEX");
    return hexHash;
  }
}

function SHA3_256Tester() {
  var test = 'test123';
  Logger.log(test); // test123
  Logger.log(SHA3_256(
  test)); // 3054762b0a8b31adfe79efb3bc7718624627cc99c7c8f39bfa591ce6854ac05d
  var test = ''; // Empty string
  Logger.log(test); // Empty string
  Logger.log(SHA3_256(
  test)); // a7ffc6f8bf1ed76651c14756a061d662f580ff4de43b49fa82d80a4b80f8434a
}
```

This function will input a string and output its SHA3-256. If you don't understand the code, please let me know to help you.

Comment: Hi there @manxuz, I repeated the test copying and pasting the code and it still working as intended, I've updated the original code to include the function that I use for testing. To be sure that I don't miss any important details of your script, could you share how are you implementing this code?

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron I think that your script works fine.

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron I apologize that I miscopied the comment. So I commented again. I noticed the OP's issue. It seems that OP wants to use the function as the custom function. And I thought that OP might put `=myFunction(test123)` to a cell. In this case, `=myFunction(test123)` returns `884bad3ef9aa410492a8c2e256fb3e3a3c9043c0dca257c185861dc1b0496518`, because `=myFunction("#NAME?")` is run. So I updated my answer. In this case, I could notice this because the hash value is the unique value.